# How should I refer to my Master's degree in professional contexts?

Tags: apprentissage, éducation

I have checked other responses but in Scotland the degree system is slightly different from other systems in the UK and abroad.

I studied a Master's degree in French at the University of Glasgow. This included 5 years of study as follows:

1. 2 years of study at my home university.
2. 1 year of university at a French university.
3. 2 year of study at my home university again.

Please note, I did not have a bachelor's degree/license before this study. In certain universities in Scotland we can obtain Master's degrees as undergraduates.

So my question: est-ce que c'est une "maîtrise" ou un "Master"?

I'm not sure if, given my year abroad, this would be considered BAC+4 or BAC+5? I would appreciate any advice as I don't want to be using the wrong term. (I can always include an explanatory note when I use the term but that seems a bit superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

À mon sens, le fait d'avoir un bac +4 ou un bac +5 dépend du nombre d'année d'étude mais surtout des crédits ECTS obtenus.

> Le **Master** est une formation qui permet d’obtenir un **Bac+5**. Le Master donne le droit à **300** crédits ETCS. En effet, s’ajoutent aux crédits ECTS de votre licence ou de votre bachelor (180), ceux du master (120).

Information about ECTS: https://ec.europa.eu/education/resources-and-tools/european-credit-transfer-and-accumulation-system-ects_en

Check out this website, you should have more info about it per the country: https://www.studyineurope.eu/ects-system

Une source équivalente en FR: https://diplomeo.com/actualite-credits_ects_european_credits_transfer_system

Answer (score 0):

The diploma called "maitrise" is now a diploma that can be delivered at the end of the first year of study in what is called the "second cycle"; it is called an intermediary diploma; the diploma called "[master](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_(France))" is delivered the next year. The "master" is what used to be called "maitrise"; you can't get it before two years' study in the "second cycle", that is not beforet the end of the "second cyle"; if you have those two years' study, either in France or in the UK, you should be able to say "master" as "master" corresponds to "master's degree" in the UK.